# Let $X\ge 0$ be an integrable random variable. Show that if $E(X)=0$ then $X=0$ almost everywhere.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X\ge 0$ be an integrable random variable. Show that if $E(X)=0$ then $X=0$ almost everywhere.

Can anybody help me in this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to proceed:

1. $\{\omega:X(\omega)>0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{\omega:X(\omega)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$, so it's enough to show that $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega:X(\omega)\geq \frac{1}{n}\})=0$ for all $n\geq 1$.
2. $X(\omega)\geq \frac{1}{n}1_{\{X\geq \frac{1}{n}\}}(\omega)$, so take expectations of both sides to conclude.